# Debian5 on VMWare Workstation, can't network out

Tags: debian

This is probably more of a Debian question than a VMWare question, but I've installed Debian 5 (from debian-503-amd64-DVD-1) through VMWare Workstation and I'm having trouble with accessing anything through the network...  I can ping anything on the LAN or the internet:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.42 ms

$ ping www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (209.85.225.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iy-in-f104.1e100.net (209.85.225.104): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=83.0 ms
```

But I can't get anywhere via TCP (using wget, lynx, or telnet)...  any of the 3 apps just hang when they try to connect...

```
$ wget http://www.google.com
--2009-11-18 09:57:57--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.95.103, 74.125.95.99, 74.125.95.147, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.95.103|:80...

$ telnet 192.168.1.222 8000
Trying 192.168.1.222...
```

(Yes, I am listening on port 8000 on that IP and can get to it from another box).

What steps can I take to troubleshoot why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Turn off all antivirus software and windows firewall.
2. `iptables -F`
3. Then wireshark(dump) packets going from virtual machine. That will probably show smth.

Comment: No antivirus running, turned off Windows Firewall (even though I was allowing VMWare through it).  What does iptables -F do?  Trying wireshark now, but I have no experience in using it.

Anything else I can do?  I ran tracert to google (somehow got there in 1 hop) and to another box on the LAN (somehow never got past the first hop).

Comment: That rule cleans firewall. What type of network connection does your virtual machine have? Bridged? Nat?

Comment: NAT, which I believe is VMWare's default.

Comment: Ugh, sorry to waste your time, it's working now, under 7.0 (I just upgraded).